# Scanner permission problem

Tags: permissions, scanner, canon

I use Canon MF-231 i-sensys. I install printer driver and all is good. But the scanner is still torturing me. Scanner not work properly.

I check scanner with `scanimage -L` and get this:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x8087/0x8000 at 002:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x8008 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x093a/0x2510 at 003:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Language Error], product=0x27d1 [Language Error]) at libusb:003:005
could not open USB device 0x1c4f/0x0026 at 003:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

Because of this Simple Scan don't work properly. I use Ubuntu 18.04.1. How can I solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Canon Pixma MG3620; Simple Scan doesn't find the scanner.  I was able to scan using the terminal and typing in "scangearmp".